# If you use a database to store $_SESSION with session_set_save_handler should you encrypt?

Tags: php

If you use a database to store $_SESSION with session_set_save_handler should yoou encrypt? If you should encrypt any recommendations on what to use to encrypt?

Comment: Is the database public? If the database is private and no-one else can access it, why bother with the extra overhead of encryption? The default session files are not encrypted - the question you need to be asking here is to ask yourself "Do *I* want/need to encrypt the data?"

Comment: What kind of data is stored in your sessions? On which environment your code runs? Do you store the information also in a persistent data store and do you encrypt this?

Comment: So I assume session data can be seen

Comment: @George If your server becomes compromised, even the default settings can make your sessions compromised. So yeah, you can get data stolen. The primary issue to ask yourself is, is your server and web site code safe? Is your SESSION data critical... why would you need to encrypt it?

Comment: Currently I have access level in my session data and if this can be seen and changed they could upgrade themselves and get greater access to my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't unless your database is less secured against unwanted reading than your source code that does the encryption and decryption (which is unlikely).